# angular multilevel child routing

Tags: routes, angular6

I've got the following configuration route grouped by modules:

On top:

```
imports: [
  ContentModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
])
```

Next module (ContentModule):

```
imports: [
  ApplicationsModule,
  RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'Content', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children:
    [
      { path: 'Apps/List', component: ApplicationListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: { applications: ApplicationListResolver } },
      { path: 'Apps/Details/:applicationID', component: ApplicationTabContainerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'Apps/NewApp', component: NewApplication, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'Documentation', component: DocComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'App/List', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'App/List' }
    ]
  }
])
```

And last module (ApplicationsModule):

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'info', component: ApplicationDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: { application: ApplicationDetailResolver } },
  { path: 'CDN', component: FileManager, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: { fileStorageData: FileManagerResolver } },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'info', pathMatch: 'full' }
])
```

Well, if I go to http://localhost:8253/Content/Apps/Details/Web-Site-App/info I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Content/Apps/Details/Portal-Web-Drupal/inf

Anyone knows why I'm getting that error?

I've structured the modules on that way because ContentComponent is rendered on first router-outlet (it has the navbar (that it's static content) and the ContentComponent). ContentComponent has a router-outlet that render a DocumentationComponent or an ApplicationListComponent or a NewApplicationComponent or an ApplicationTabContainerComponent. ApplicationTabContainerComponent has a router-outlet that can render an ApplicationDetailComponent or a FileManagerComponent.

Maybe, the problem is that I can't have more than two levels of router-outlets, and I've got three:

- grandparent is router-outlet of application, that render the content component
- parent (ContentComponent) is a router-outlet that render applicationList or newApplication or applicationTabContainer
- childs that are components that render inside ApplicationTabContainerComponent router-outlet.

Comment: ApplicationTabContainerComponent is missing the `children` route property. Otherwise there is nothing to tie the routes defined in Applications module to that route. (I'm out of the office and will post a more thorough answer when I get back if no one else does first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To establish the hierarchy you need two things:

1) The router outlet in the parent component (which it sounds like you have).

2) The `children` property (when the routes are defined in the module) or `loadChildren` property (when the routes are defined in a separate module) for the parent route to let the router know which routes are the child routes.

ApplicationTabContainerComponent is missing the `children` or `loadChildren` route property. Otherwise there is nothing to tie the routes defined in Applications module to that route.

It's a bit challenging to get the syntax just right without having the code ... but it will look something like this:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'Content', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children:
    [
      { path: 'Apps/List', component: ApplicationListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], resolve: { applications: ApplicationListResolver } },
      { 
        path: 'Apps/Details/:applicationID', 
        component: ApplicationTabContainerComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        loadChildren: './yourpath/applications.module#ApplicationsModule`
      },
      { path: 'Apps/NewApp', component: NewApplication, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'Documentation', component: DocComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'App/List', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'App/List' }
    ]
  }
])
```

This syntax may not be exactly correct, but should give you the idea. (I've only used `loadChildren` on component-less routes.)

I talk through an example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ

Comment: Thanks so much, you're amazing. You allways have the solution!!